# how to close submenu with slideUp and slideDown jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to close the submenu with this method, pushing the id's up and down, at this moment the code slideDown the submenu, pushes the ID's down...i want to close and slideUp the ID's...any thoughts, thanks in advance!

```
var submenu;    

$('.menu-desktop li').click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#intro-home, #breadcrumbs-pc').animate({'margin-top':'2.4rem'}, 100)
    $('.menu-desktop ul:not(:first-child)').slideUp(100)
    $('.menu-desktop').find('.'+id).delay(200).slideDown(100)
    $('#intro-home, #breadcrumbs-pc').delay(200).animate({'margin-top':'5rem'}, 100) 


    $('.menu-desktop').find('.'+id).slideToggle("fast")
});
```

Comment: I would need to see the HTML of what you're wanting to `slideUp()/ slideDown()`.  Most likely though, you'll be wanting to use `slideToggle()`

Comment: doesn't let me paste the html code as it is! I add the slideToggle, but does animated it all at once! i know i missing something...

Comment: Ok, the HTML it's here http://jsfiddle.net/a66nN/ any thoghts, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsFiddle out and see if that does what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/droppedonjapan/a66nN/3/

Here's the meat:

```
$('.main-menu li').click(function(){
    var elems = $('ul:not(.main-menu)').length;
    var $refClass = $('.' + $(this).attr('data-ref'));
    var visible = $refClass.is(':visible');

    $('ul:not(.main-menu)').slideUp(100, function() {
        if (elems == 1) {
            if (!visible) $refClass.slideDown('fast');
        }
        elems--;
    });
});
```

I use a callback on the slideUp() function.  This is called every time an element completes the slideUp animation.  When the last element finishes hiding, if the menu that you were trying to show/ hide wasn't visible then it will show it.  If it was visible, it won't do anything after the menu hides itself.

Comment: where is the space, i need and if or else them $('.menu-desktop').find('.'+id).slideToggle("fast")

Comment: hi Dropped.on.Caprica, i have tried your solution but creates conflict with the slider under the menu!

Comment: hi Dropped.on.Caprica - your solution works now! But i need the animation make the div up again look at the example modified - http://jsfiddle.net/a66nN/7/

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused what you need!  You're wanting the margin-top set for the black div?  Something like this work?  http://jsfiddle.net/droppedonjapan/a66nN/8/